# NSIS visual studio color/font/intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, nsis

Does anybody have a color/font/intellisense add in for editing of NSIS files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit [usertype.dat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28VS.71%29.aspx) file for a bit of syntax highlighting, but it's nicer to use an editor which has support for NSIS files (any Scintilla based editor - SciTE, Notepad++, Notepad2)

Comment: Thanks for the info

I already have enough editors on my machine so with only a quick installer required, I really didn't want to load another.

I added a bunch of NSIS keywords and it seems to do the job; enough to provide some coloring on syntax. At least I no longer looking at just black and white.

Needed to map the .NSI to Visual C++ editing experience in the Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension

Comment: @BlueShepherd, do you mind sharing what you added so we can build on that?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested yet but this probably does the trick: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e57fe9a-ae5d-4740-a1c3-7a8e278e105b

Comment: Tried installing it, might just be my computer but all it did was give null reference exceptions and crash visual studio.

Comment: I couldn't make it run to. It's still beta though. I hope they will make it work as it looks promising.